# how to convert curl command in Invoke-RestMethod of powershell

Tags: powershell, curl

I need to convert the following command from bash curl to powershell syntax:

```
curl -s --head --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:XXXXXX" "https://gitlab.XXXXXX/api/v4/projects/${id}/issues?state=all&per_pages=100"
```

This one in particular to get value of `X-Total-Page` from results.

I've tried to convert with this, but doesn't works:

```
function getPageNumbers ($myId)
    {

        $privateToken = "myToken" 

        $headers = @{"PRIVATE-TOKEN"="$privateToken"}

        $url = "https://gitlab.XXXXXX/api/v4/projects/$myId/issues?state=all&per_pages=100"

        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Head -Uri "$url" -Header $headers  -ContentType "text/json" 


        return $result
    }
```

maybe because the `"Head"` method is used only for `Invoke-Webrequest` ?

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what about `Invoke-webrequest`?

Comment: ok I'll try to move on Invoke-webRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not seeing the body. But you can add that. You can do something like this:

```
$privateToken = "myToken" 
$headers = @{"PRIVATE-TOKEN"="$privateToken"}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://gitlab.XXXXXX/api/v4/projects/$myId/issues?state=all&per_pages=100" -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $headers -Method Post
```

I would also suggest you to go through the [CURL to Invoke-WebRequest](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7aec7t/curl_to_invokewebrequest/?st=jeftfqqs&sh=12bb8033)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this: `$R= Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"   -Method Get -UseBasicParsing` and with `$R.Content` I can see the whole text but I'm now trying to parse it ...

Comment: you can convert that to json using `$R.Content | Convertto-Json -Depth 3`. You can handle the parsing part in multiple ways. But atleast your curl got converted to Invoke-webrequest now

Comment: yes I found it, but this is the right one that I need `$x = $R.Content | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: @ClaudioM: That makes better sense if the content is already in json;)

Comment: why do you suggest Invoke-WebRequest over Invoke-RestMethod

Comment: @GoldenLion: `Invoke-RestMethod` differs from `Invoke-WebRequest` by its passing ability.`Invoke-RestMethod` natively understands the output a REST API method returns, which is typically JSON. When the API does return JSON, `Invoke-RestMethod` will parse the JSON and return useful PowerShell objects

Comment: For my purposes, I need json so Invoke-RestMethod would be best.